# Django django.utils.timezone.make_aware not adding default timezone

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

Naive datetime not properly converted in timezoned datetime by django timezone.make_aware

My application is handling some strings representing datetime, for example:

```
2019-05-20 15:47:19
```

I'm receiving these data from an external API so I don't have control over the received values.
I'm trying to set this datetime in my python model using the following code:

```py
datetime_to_parse = '2019-05-20 15:47:19'
my_model.start = timezone.make_aware(datetime.strptime(datetime_to_parse, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
my_model.save()
```

What I'm obtaining is the following error:

```
DateTimeField Event.start received a naive datetime (2019-05-20 15:47:19) while time zone support is active
```

Since I'm calling make_aware I expect the datetime to be automatically converted in a timezoned datetime using the timezone specified in my django settings.

My django settings contain the following definition:

```
TIME_ZONE = "Europe/Zurich"
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I can not reproduce this. I get `datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 20, 15, 47, 19, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Zurich' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)`. Did you set `USE_TZ` to `True`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes I set USE_TZ = True, in fact if I set USE_TZ to False I have no problems. the fact is that I want to use the timezone but django is not implicitly using it in the make_aware function